# Django Query set defer and only not working

Tags: django, query-optimization

I have a 2 models, a house and a message.  A message has FK to a house:

```
model House:
   attribute1 = models.CharField("")
   ...more stuff...

model Message:
   house = models.ForeignKey(House)
   ...more stuff...
```

I created 15 messages all with house_id = 3 using: Message(house_id = 3).save()

My problem is how slow the query is taking.  When I do:

```
Message.objects.filter(house_id = 3)
```

I get the following queries:

```
{u'time': u'0.030', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id`, `home_message`.`house_id`,       FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`house_id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.027', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`,  FROM `home_house` WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.027', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`,  FROM `home_house` WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.027', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`,  FROM `home_house` WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
```

... (15 times, one for each message)

So I am seeing that I get a database query for EVERY house_id in my Message.  Note that I only query for Messages ONCE (as expected).

Obviously this is rather slow, so I try:

```
Message.objects.filter(house_id = 3).defer('house')
```

Surprisingly this made it worse.  The queries are now:

```
{u'time': u'0.028', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id` FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`house_id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.024', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id`, `home_message`.`house_id` FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`id` = 1 '}
{u'time': u'0.027', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`, ` FROM `home_house` WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.024', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id`, `home_message`.`house_id` FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`id` = 2 '}
{u'time': u'0.027', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`, ` FROM `home_house` WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
...x15...
```

I am now making a query for EACH message individually AND for each house foreign key - essentially doubling the number of calls.

That did not work.  So now I try the django "only".

```
Message.objects.filter(house_id = house_id).only("id").  # only get id!
```

The queries I am now sending:

```
{u'time': u'0.025', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id` FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`house_id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.024', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id`, `home_message`.`house_id` FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`id` = 1 '}
{u'time': u'0.026', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`,  WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
{u'time': u'0.024', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_message`.`id`, `home_message`.`house_id` FROM `home_message` WHERE `home_message`.`id` = 2 '}
{u'time': u'0.026', u'sql': u'SELECT `home_house`.`id`, `home_house`.`is_active`,  WHERE `home_house`.`id` = 3 '}
```

...x15...

So once again, I am getting the dreaded house object query and another query for full Message by id (like the defer command).

I do not understand if this is the correct behavior for ONLY and DEFER.  I wish to only get the information (as an object, or I would use "values" - which does work btw.) without evaluating the FK.

Edit:

The error was in the **unicode** where I called
return self.house

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a few misunderstandings about Django querysets in general, and what `defer` and `only` are supposed to do in particular.

`defer(fieldname)` means "Don't query for 'fieldname' now, wait until I ask for it later". So naturally, since you then proceed to ask for 'house' immediately, you will get double queries.

`only(fieldname)` means - as the name implies - "only give me 'fieldname'". So I don't know why you would be surprised that then referring to other fields than 'id' would trigger a further query.

However, you should note that neither of those has anything to do with your actual problem: the correct tool to use there is `select_related()`, which as the documentation explains is for following the ForeignKey in a single query.

Comment: my understanding of the "defer" query seems to match yours, though I may be using it incorrectly?   When I do:       Message.objects.filter(house_id = 3).defer('house'), I thought it should defer the call for the "house" but you can still filter by the house_id.  I do not understand where I am asking for "house" in my code?  

About the "only(fieldname)", I am not asking for ANY other information.  I tell it to print the returned query on: 
print(Message.objects.filter(house_id = house_id).only("id")).  Am i acciently calling for the other fieldnames?

Also I will look into select_related.